# Slick.js: Get current and total slides (ie. 3/5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Using [Slick.js](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick) - how does one get current and total slides (ie. 3/5) as a simpler alternative to the dots?

I've been told I can use the `customPaging` callback using the callback argument objects, but what does that mean exactly?

```
$('.slideshow').slick({
    slide: 'img',
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    customPaging: function (slider, i) {
        return slider.slickCurrentSlide + '/' + (i + 1);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/cpdqhdwy/1/

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The `slider` object contains the slide count as property.

### Slick < 1.5

```
$('.slideshow').slick({
    slide: 'img',
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    dotsClass: 'custom_paging',
    customPaging: function (slider, i) {
        //FYI just have a look at the object to find available information
        //press f12 to access the console in most browsers
        //you could also debug or look in the source
        console.log(slider);
        return  (i + 1) + '/' + slider.slideCount;
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ve7tykL2/)**

### Update for Slick 1.5+ (tested until 1.8.1)

```
var $status = $('.pagingInfo');
var $slickElement = $('.slideshow');

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
    var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
    $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
});

$slickElement.slick({
    slide: 'img',
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/k3g9snx1/)

### Update for Slick 1.9+

```
var $status = $('.pagingInfo');
var $slickElement = $('.slideshow');

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
    var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
    $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);
});

$slickElement.slick({
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/tjwo23L8/)

### Example when using `slidesToShow`

```
var $status = $('.pagingInfo');
var $slickElement = $('.slideshow');

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
  // no dots -> no slides
  if(!slick.$dots){
    return;
  }
  
  //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
  var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
  // use dots to get some count information
  $status.text(i + '/' + (slick.$dots[0].children.length));
});

$slickElement.slick({
  infinite: false,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  autoplay: true,
  dots: true
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/g08soeum/)

Comment: Awesome! But how would one display the right paging for each slide? `1/3` on the first, `2/3` on the second etc.?

Comment: you want to place the paging information on the slides ?

Comment: Yep. If you remove `customPaging` and `dotsClass` altogether you can see how Slick originally does this. But I believe `N/N` would be a tad more minimalistic. http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/2uhtas91/3/ is wrong obviously but..

Comment: there's any way to do this in angular version of slick? thank you

Comment: `ul.slick-dots {
              li {
                &.slick-active {
                  display: block;
                }
                display: none;
              }
            }` with this SCSS I got the correct item to display. Works well enough thanks!

Comment: Make sure you define the init event listener BEFORE your init slick code or it won't do anything.

Comment: could do $status.html( '<span class="current_slide">' + i + '</span> / <span class="total_slides"> ' + slick.slideCount + '</span>'); if you wanna style the paginations ! awesome answer

Comment: How would you handle if the there were more slides and wouldn't be infinite? Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/rvz0eytk/
It gives you wrong numbers for slick.slideCount

Comment: In that case you cant use `slick.slideCount` info, but the information is avialable via `slick.$dots[0].children.length`. Heres an example http://jsfiddle.net/rLckgsxh/

Comment: Great job for updating this one, the last one works perfectly!

Comment: When all the slides fit into the screen the arrows & dots disappear as per default functionality, but the pagination text would obviously remain. I couldn't find any specific parameter returning for such a case, but used the `slick.$nextArrow.hasClass('slick-hidden')` to test for it. Just modified the one line there `slick.$nextArrow.hasClass('slick-hidden') ? $paginator.text('') : $status.text(i + '/' + slick.slideCount);`

Answer (score 6):

You need to bind init before initialization.

```
$('.slider-for').on('init', function(event, slick){
        $(this).append('<div class="slider-count"><p><span id="current">1</span> von <span id="total">'+slick.slideCount+'</span></p></div>');
    });
    $('.slider-for').slick({
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      arrows: true,
      fade: true
    });
    $('.slider-for')
        .on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
            // finally let's do this after changing slides
            $('.slider-count #current').html(currentSlide+1);
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

I use this code and it works:

.slider - this is slider block

.count - selector which use for return counter

```
$(".slider").on("init", function(event, slick){
    $(".count").text(parseInt(slick.currentSlide + 1) + ' / ' + slick.slideCount);
});

$(".slider").on("afterChange", function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    $(".count").text(parseInt(slick.currentSlide + 1) + ' / ' + slick.slideCount);
});
$(".page-article-item_image-slider").slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    arrows: true
});
```

Comment: Wanted to know the actual number of slides excluding the cloned ones, slick.slideCount helped me to . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

This might help:

- You don't need to enable dots or customPaging.
- Position .slick-counter with CSS.

**CSS**

```
.slick-counter{
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  background:yellow;
  padding:5px;
  opacity:0.8;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var $el = $('.slideshow');

$el.slick({
  slide: 'img',
  autoplay: true,
  onInit: function(e){
    $el.append('<div class="slick-counter">'+ parseInt(e.currentSlide + 1, 10) +' / '+ e.slideCount +'</div>');
  },
  onAfterChange: function(e){
    $el.find('.slick-counter').html(e.currentSlide + 1 +' / '+e.slideCount);
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cpdqhdwy/6/

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with multiple slides. version `1.8.1`

if `slidesToShow` and `slidesToScroll` more than `1`

trick is in `slick.slickGetOption('slidesToShow');`

```
$(".your-selector").on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
    var slidesToShow = slick.slickGetOption('slidesToShow');
    var curPage = parseInt((i-1)/slidesToShow) + 1;
    var lastPage =  parseInt((slick.slideCount-1)/slidesToShow) + 1;
    $('.your-selector').text(curPage);
    $('.your-selector').text(lastPage);
});
```

Note `curPage` and `lastPage` is separate. I had to color them differently.

Based on top-voted answer

Comment: thank you soo much. i was in the same case as above. this works great

Answer (score 2):

Based on the first proposition posted by @Mx. (posted sept.15th 2014) I created a variant to get a decent HTML markup for [ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Accessibilit%C3%A9/ARIA) support.

```
$('.slideshow').slick({
    slide: 'img',
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    dotsClass: 'custom_paging',
    customPaging: function (slider, i) {
        //FYI just have a look at the object to find available information
        //press f12 to access the console in most browsers
        //you could also debug or look in the source
        console.log(slider);
        var slideNumber   = (i + 1),
            totalSlides = slider.slideCount;
        return '<a class="custom-dot" role="button" title="' + slideNumber + ' of ' + totalSlides + '"><span class="string">' + slideNumber + '</span></a>';
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MartinDubeNet/fdtx1k8s/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Using the previous method with more than 1 slide at time was giving me the wrong total so I've used the "dotsClass", like this (on v1.7.1):

// JS

```
var slidesPerPage = 6

$(".slick").on("init", function(event, slick){
   maxPages = Math.ceil(slick.slideCount/slidesPerPage);
   $(this).find('.slider-paging-number li').append('/ '+maxPages);
});

$(".slick").slick({
   slidesToShow: slidesPerPage,
   slidesToScroll: slidesPerPage,
   arrows: false,
   autoplay: true,
   dots: true,
   infinite: true,
   dotsClass: 'slider-paging-number'
});
```

// CSS

```
ul.slider-paging-number {
    list-style: none;
    li {
        display: none;
        &.slick-active {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        button {
            background: none;
            border: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually worked for me - but it throws up errors in the console saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null" which means that it's calling slick twice :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
Modifications are done to the new Slick version 1.7.1.
```

Here is a updated script example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhn_sos/cpdqhdwy/140/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want page numbering:

Example: **1** 2 3 4...

HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div class="slider-number"><span>1 2 3 4...</span></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div class="slider-number"><span>1 2 3 4...</span></div>
  </div>
  ...
  ...
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.slider').on('init reInit afterChange',
    function(event, slick, currentSlide){
        var status = $(this).find('.slider-number span');
        //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
        var i = slick.currentSlide;
        var slidesLength = slick.slideCount;
        var numberSlide1 = i + 1 <= slidesLength ? i + 1 : i - (slidesLength - 1);
        var numberSlide2 = i + 2 <= slidesLength ? i + 2 : i - (slidesLength - 2);
        var numberSlide3 = i + 3 <= slidesLength ? i + 3 : i - (slidesLength - 3);
        var numberSlide4 = i + 4 <= slidesLength ? i + 4 : i - (slidesLength - 4);

        status.html('<strong>'+numberSlide1+'</strong>' + ' ' +
            numberSlide2 + ' ' +
            numberSlide3 + ' ' +
            numberSlide4 + '...');
});
```

[**JsFiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/arbuzzzi/t3sqzd18/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count to update before the slide is changed, here is an approach as of Slick 1.8+

```
var slidesCountEl = $('<div class="slick-slides-count" />');

$('.slick-slider').on('init reInit beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  var slickEl = $(event.target);

  if ( !slickEl.find('.slick-slides-count').length ) {

    slidesCountEl.prependTo( slickEl );

    slidesCountEl = slickEl.find('.slick-slides-count');

  }

  var currentSlideCount = (nextSlide ? nextSlide : 0) + 1;

  slidesCountEl.html( currentSlideCount + '<span>/</span>' + slick.slideCount );

});
```