# Slick.js display current slide and total num of slides

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm having trouble getting the current and total number of slides to display below a slick.js slideshow. Thanks for your help!!

```
$('.recipeThumbs').slick({
    dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4,
    infinite: true,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        dots: false,
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        dots: false,
        arrows: true,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

I actually found an answer to my question on another stackoverflow post. Here's a link to it :)

[Slick.js: Get current and total slides (ie. 3/5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847297/slick-js-get-current-and-total-slides-ie-3-5)