# Slick.js count number by page

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, slick.js

Hi referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847297/slick-js-get-current-and-total-slides-ie-3-5), the js is count by slide. My slidetoshow is 3 per page. How can I make it count by page? That mean

- 1/3
- 2/3
- 3/3

Here's my result for now:

- 1/3
- 4/3
- 7/3

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        if (!slick.$dots) {
            return;
        }

        var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
        $status.text(i + ' / ' + slick.$dots[0].children.length);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about just recalculate it ?

```
var perPage = 3;
var total = slick.$dots[0].children.length;
var i = currentSlide > 0 ? currentSlide/perPage : 0;
$status.text(i + ' / ' + total);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's working now and just need to add + 1 from your code.


`var i = (currentSlide > 0 ? currentSlide/perPage : 0) + 1;`
Thank you so much!